# How to Use Domainkeys and DKIM both with exim on freebsd server machine

Tags: freebsd, exim, mta

I have setup exim mta on freebsd.

I have also setup DKIM on this machine and my mails are properly signed.

I want to know how to setup **Domainkeys** along with DKIM on exim so that my mails are signedf both by Domainkeys as well DKIM.

This is because gmail honors DKIM as well yahoo honors Domainkeys.

Comment: DKIM is the successor to the DomainKeys standard.  I would hope anybody supporting DomainKeys would also support DKIM by now.  [Yahoo claims they support DKIM](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN3435.html?impressions=true).

Comment: @cjm thank you for letting me know, yahoo's support about DKIM. But yet yahoo is not accepting my mails ... whereas Google is.

Comment: DKIM merely lets you prove that a particular email is authentically from your domain.  It doesn't mean that the email isn't spam.  If you have a valid DKIM signature, but Yahoo is rejecting your email, adding DomainKeys is unlikely to help.  Does Yahoo give you any [error message](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/email-blocked-yahoo-mail-sln3444.html?impressions=true)?

Comment: @cjm may be this a reason.

I am not getting any error msg. And moreover i never send any email from my this new created server before this time. so how yahoo can spam me while google is not doing.